# Printing a .txt or .PRN file over a TCP/IP Printer by CMD command

Tags: cmd, tcp, printing

I am trying with no success in printing a .txt or .prn file over a TCP/IP printer by CMD command line.

The specific command I am using is:

`print /d:\\192.168.2.105\Intermec1 REPORT.txt`

in response to the above, I expected the specified file to be printed by the specified printer. Instead
I get the following output:

"Impossibile inizializzare il dispositivo \192.168.2.105\Intermec1" (in italian)

"It is impossible to initialize the device \192.168.2.105\Intermec1" (Eng translated)

Further information:

- The printer is connected (by ETH cable) directly to the PC I execute the command.
- Pinging over that address (192.168.2.105) works fine.
- If I execute a printing page test by Windows tool, it works fine.

I would appreciate any help.
Thanks in advanced

Comment: `\\192.168.2.105\Intermec1` is `\\servername\share`, where `servername` is a *computer*, not a printer and `share` is the shared name of the printer *on that computer*. A *printer* has no share. ([Source](https://ss64.com/nt/print.html))

Comment: Hi Stephan, Thank you for the correction. I have changed the command as following: `print /d:\\192.168.2.20\Intermec1 REPORT.txt` . I still get, as a feed back, the message: "It is impossible to initialize the device \192.168.2.20\Intermec1"